# can't change cell hight based on background color swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell, background-color

I'm trying to make an app that changes cell heights based on their background colors. I want to have it so that the cells will be smaller if their background colors are cyan or orange, but I can't seem to find the right way to do it. I have the code to change the height, but I don't know the correct parameter to use.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
               heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 1 {//should be if cell.backgroundcolor or something
        return 100 //noncolored cells
    } else {
        return 20 // colored cells
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you been able to resovle this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the array of the object to determine which one should have which height. At least create array of booleans that will keep that information. Here, this is very questionable will this ever work since cells are reusable.

I would suggest that you use same condition you have in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to set cells background.